# 3 Random Fruits, but only 2 Random Recepies. How to Cook this Random Generator?

Tags: php, list, random, include

imagine I have a list of 50 favourite fruits, but I want only to get 3 random from that list in my short elevator pitch on my webpage to show off my favourite fruits:

*file contents of [ favfruits.php ]*

```
$fruitsarray = Mango, Banana, Cucumber, Pear, Peach, Suthern Melon, Coconut, ...
$recepyarray = Juices, Oven Dishes, Freshly Served, Ripe after 14 days, ...

# echo randomizer function: echoes random words from any list
```

*file contents [ webpage.php ]*

```
<html><body>
<?php # show 3 fruits randomly   ?> 
<p> can be used for example in: </p>
<?php # show 2 recepies randomly ?> 
</body><html>
```

**Question1: is this A) a job on its own, or B) just 2 lines of code? or C)??**
**If A)** which different PHP methods would you suggest for this!
**If B)** thanks very much for helping me on my way to cook this!
**If C)** make your free suggestions!

Comment: Are all recipes applicable to all fruit combinations?

Comment: Yeah... what do the recipes have to do with anything? All you've told us is that you want 3 random fruit, and mentioned nothing about what the recipes are used for.

Comment: Sorry: in my openminded experimental kitchen lifestyle, there are no limitations as to what fruit could go into what recepy so `YES` all fruits can go into all recepies: they have no relation/dependancy if you ask me! Thanks for asking and sorry I forgot to point out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PHP has an efficient, built-in function for this. [array_rand](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php)

```
// get 3 random keys from your array
$keys = array_rand($fruitsarray, 3);

// cycle through the keys to get the values
foreach ($keys as $key) {
    echo $fruitsarray[$key];
}
```

Then, just modify for the recipes.

Comment: PHP always does this to me! I think "Oh, I'll just shuffle the array and then take the first 3 elements..." but then PHP goes and 1-ups me.. they have a function that does the whole darn thing.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if I understood what you want, but maybe [shuffle()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php) will do the trick.

```
$fruitsarray = array(...);
$recepyarray = array(...);
shuffle($fruitsarray);
shuffle($recepyarray);
...
echo $fruitsarray[0] . ', ' . $fruitsarray[1] . ', ' . $fruitsarray[2];
...
echo $recepyarray[0] . ', ' . $recepyarray[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Three random fruits may happen to fit none of your recipes. I'd suggest you:

- Choose a random fruit;
- Select recipes that include this fruit, scan through them until you spot two more common fruits in these recipes.
- This may fail; then you'll need to retry with another random fruit.

The process may be time-consuming; if so, you could generate several known sets of fruits and recipes as a batch job at night, then make the site randomly choose one of these pre-calculated sets of fruits and recipes.

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to try to make a short solution here

```
//echo randomizer function: echoes random words from any list

    function echo_randomizer($array, $length=3, $sep=",") {
         shuffle($array);
         echo implode($sep,array_slice($array, 0, $length));
    }
```